# Generated, namespaced POCO classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

(*I feel like I'm missing something important here.*)

I'm creating a WCF Data Service (5.0) using the "database first" approach for the entities.

I've created tables with "*namespaced*" names, using the `.` (*dot*) such as `[Entertainment.Event]` and `[Promotions.Event]`.

The EF 4.x POCO generator template of course knocks these out, via the call to `CSharpCodeProvider.CreateEscapedIdentifier()`.

I'd like very much to generate (*and regenerate, and appropriately map*) **namespaced POCOs**; specifically, preserving the implied namespaces of the tables.

What am I looking at as far as accomplishing this? I'm guessing it will involve awhile's worth of swimming through T4 templates.

Ultimately, is this doable?

Comment: I don't see how that would work - the properties of the context that represent the tables would be `DataContext.Entertainment.Events`, `Datacontext.Promotions.Events`, etc. which would be invalid.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, you are right. I suppose this would necessitate an additional context per namespace as suggested below, or some sort of aliasing. I'm guessing I'll have to explore multiple contexts.

Comment: @DStanley Alternatively, this specific issue could be handled in the template; building a list of potential property names, and namespace qualifying pairs (*or more*) of collisions prior to generation. Thus, `EntertainmentEvents` and `PromotionsEvents` would be the context's properties, but related entities would merely have `Events` (*provided they didn't also reference both event types*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to create one context per your DB schema, placing each one into whatever namespace you like.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBelov, however, what about relationships between entities in different contexts? Following my example tables; an `Entertainment.Event` and a `Promotions.Event` may each occur at the same `Location`

Comment: @Bracketworks There has been a good discussion about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158986/how-to-relate-objects-from-multiple-contexts-using-the-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks @SergeBelov. I guess I have some reading to do, and remodeling considerations to make; my understanding of EF is less than complete, however this seems to have been made more complicated than necessary.